# Getting same error, "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" in different projects that I clone from gitHub

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error, web-frontend

I have cloned several projects from gitHub most of which are react web applications. Upon trying to run App.js I get the error: `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`". In the terminal the issue is generally addressed in the following section:

```
function App (props) {

................


}
```

Here is the App.js file that I'm currently trying to run:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SideBar from "./components/SideBar/SideBar";
import Chat from "./components/Chat/Chat";
import "./assets/css/index.css";
import "./assets/css/tailwind.css";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import axiosInstance from "./helpers/axiosInstance";
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import FirstOverview from "./components/FirstOverview/FirstOverview";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Login from "./components/Login/Login";
import * as actions from "./store/actions/index";
import Logout from "./components/Logout/Logout";

function App(props) {
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.onCheckSignIn();
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    //We have to fetch inital rooms
    axiosInstance
      .get("/rooms/sync")
      .then((response) => {
        setRooms(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const pusher = new Pusher("1e4a066974f307cf86f1", {
      cluster: "eu",
    });

    const channelRooms = pusher.subscribe("rooms");
    channelRooms.bind("inserted", (newRoom) => {
      setRooms([...rooms, newRoom]);
    });

    return () => {
      channelRooms.unbind_all();
      channelRooms.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [rooms]);

  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  );
  if (props.isAuthenticated) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/rooms">
          <SideBar rooms={rooms} />
          <FirstOverview />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/rooms/:roomId">
          <div className="hidden md:block">
            <SideBar rooms={rooms} />
          </div>
          <Chat />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/logout">
          <Logout />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/rooms" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="header" />
      <div className="app__body ">{routes}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onCheckSignIn: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckStatus()),
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

And the current error is exactly as the following:

*file:///C:/Users/usAme/Desktop/whatsapp-clone-frontend/src/app.js:49
`<Switch>`
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'*

When I comment out the whole `<Switch>` section, I get the same (Unexpected token) error for `<div className="app">` section.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "whatsapp-mern-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/standalone": "^7.21.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "firebase": "^9.17.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.2",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-emoji": "^0.5.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.1.21",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.0",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss src/assets/css/tailwind.css -o src/assets/css/index.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/assets/css/tailwind.css -o src/assets/css/index.css -w",
    "start": "yarn run watch:css & react-scripts start",
    "build": "yarn run build:css & react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried different node versions but it didn't work. I suspect the issue is related to importing/exporting modules but I have no idea how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Added `"start": "react-scripts start"` to package.json, and changed index.js to:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and run the App.js with "npm start" instead of "node app.js"!